# How should i save value of textbox in database as 1,2,3,etc format in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to insert a value of textbox in the database and save it in the column `joiner_id`.

When I execute same form and add next value textbox.

Value is saved in same field in, separated format of same column in same id of table like `1,2,3...`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to make use of a relation between two tables. This means that one value gets stored in a 'description' table which has its own ID, and that ID is stored in your joiner_id.

If this is the case I would try to read the Laravel documentation about relationships, which will explain how you can setup a relation and get that specific text-value by id. [Laravel Documentation about Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Yup, this is a much better approach than comma-separated strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more explicit about what you want to achieve. I'm not sure if I get this right, but what I think you want, it's a simple iteration for your `joiner_id`.

If so, you can achieve this using `{{$loop->iteration}}` as value for your joiner_id.

More information about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly maybe you want to join two table with one to many relationship you should use bridge table instead of saving it in a same table.